# iis authentication username password

Tags: asp.net, iis, authentication, automation

I want to write script or batch file for changing iis authentication username password. Can I do this with script or batch file? or how can I do it? I have to do it automaticly.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525309%28VS.90%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

IIS provide service for users, roles etc. with those u can change user data.

Comment: How can I do this automaticly (not by hand maybe script or batch file or etc.)

Comment: A computer should be able to do this automatically for you